# I want to create a similar table with similar data types in MySQL

Tags: mysql, oracle

There is an Excel file with 10 columns and 219024 rows.
In oracle 11g I create table.

```
CREATE TABLE USER_BANCU.RE_20_03_2017
(
  IDNO NUMBER,
  DATA_REG DATE,
  DEN_COM VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  FORMA_ORG VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  ADRESA VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  LIST_COND VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  LISTA_FOND NVARCHAR2 (2000),
  GEN_ACT_NE_LIC VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  GEN_ACT_LIC VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE),
  STATUTUL VARCHAR2 (1024 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE TBS_DTI_USERS
RESULT_CACHE (MODE DEFAULT)
PCTUSED 0
PCTFREE 10
INITRANS 1
MAXTRANS 255
STORAGE (
            INITIAL 64K
            NEXT 1M
            MINEXTENTS 1
            MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE 0
            BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING
NOCOMPRESS
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING;
```

In this table I import all the rows from the file.
It's all right.
I want to create a similar table with similar data types in MySQL.

How in MySQL will these types of data be?

Oracle NVARCHAR2 (2000)    - MySQL ?

Comment: 5s google search result: [Oracle and MySQL compared](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#BABHHAJC). Section: 2.3.2 Default Data Type Mappings

Comment: Oracle NVARCHAR2 (2000)    - MySQL ?

Comment: Please read all article and you will find the differences. Sorry but no one will do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**For examples:**

```
CREATE TABLE `USER_BANCU.RE_20_03_2017` (
  `IDNO` mediumint(9) DEFAULT '100',
  `DATA_REG` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEN_COM` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORMA_ORG` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADRESA` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIST_COND` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LISTA_FOND` longtext CHARACTER SET latin1,
  `GEN_ACT_NE_LIC` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `GEN_ACT_LIC` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUTUL` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```